# Validate 4 different messages in the “.featute” but in a single step in the “.rb”

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I use the Cucumber + Capybara + Ruby framework and am not able to perform an assertion using the "expect" method.

I need to validate 4 different messages in the “.featute” but in a single step in the “.rb”

```
Given(/^I send a get to see four titles$/) do
    @api = HTTParty.get("https://jsonplcaholder.typicode.com/posts")
end

Then(/^Returned status code "(.*?)"$/) do |statuscode|
    expect(@api.code.to_s).to eq statuscode
end

Then(^Returnered message "(.*?)"$/) do |message|
    expect(@api[0]["title"]).to eq message
    expect(@api[1]["title"]).to eq message
    expect(@api[2]["title"]).to eq message
    expect(@api[3]["title"]).to eq message
end

Feature: message body
@titles
Scenario: Display of title all films
Given I send a get to see four titles
Then Returned status code "200"
Then Returned message "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit"
Then Returned message "qui est esse"
Then Returned message "ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut"
Then Returned message "eum et est occaecati"
```

Comment: Can you please specify the kind of errors, if possible with an error message, you face?

Comment: Possibly you are missing the regex slash here `Then(/^`

Answer (score 0):

message return:

```
  expected: "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit"
       got: "qui est esse"

  (compared using ==)
   (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
  ./features/step_definitions/backend11.rb:12:in `/^Returnered message "(.*?)"$/'
  features/backend11.feature:7:in `Then Returnered message "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit"'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading this right you are expecting:

@api[0]["title"] == "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit"

@api[1]["title"] == "qui est esse"

and so on.

However your code is expecting:

@api[0]["title"] == "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit"

@api[1]["title"] == "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit"

...

@api[0]["title"] == "qui est esse"

@api[1]["title"] == "qui est esse"

You can make this work a few different ways, but one of these 2 should work for you.

1)

Include the text inside the step defecation instead of passing it in.

```
Then(^I get four titles$/) do

    expect(@api[0]["title"]).to eq 'sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit'

    expect(@api[1]["title"]).to eq 'qui est esse'

    expect(@api[2]["title"]).to eq 'ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut'

    expect(@api[3]["title"]).to eq 'eum et est occaecati'

end
```

2)

If you don't care what the actual text is, just that it's there, you can use a regular expression.

```
Then(^I get four titles$/) do                
    (0..3).each do |title_count|
       expect(@api[title_count]["title"]).to match /[a-z]+/
    end        
end
```